# Create extended fields to users for futur authentification using liferay

Tags: jakarta-ee, liferay, portlet, portal

I would like to develop an application that allows to add multiple profiles with specific informations relating to a profile such as a teacher and the subject he teaches.
I like that the teacher have the right to access some `portlets` after authentication.

The main problem is in DB,should i  create a separate table for teacher that contains a foreign key related with the user table of liferay or what ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Same to you, i created a table with foreign key to USER_ table, so you can.

Comment: do you think this is the best way to extend users !

Comment: Finally i used service builder and i created a table with foreign key to USER_ table and it works

Comment: You should post as answer to close your question :)